# Как сложить элементы двух списков?

Tags: python

Пример:

```
numbers([1,2,3], [3,4,5])    -> [4,6,8]
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Вариант 1:

если изменение исходных списков не критично.

```
# заполнение переменных
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3]

# если разные длины списков, то короткий список расширяем нулями
a.extend([0,] * (len(b) - len(a)))
b.extend([0,] * (len(a) - len(b)))

# обработка
с = map(sum, zip(a,b))

# вывод результата
print(list(c))
```

Результат:

> [2, 4, 6, 4]

#### Вариант 2:

Если важно сохранить начальные списки, то попробуем по другому:

```
# заполнение переменных
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3]

# обработка
c = map(sum, zip(a + [0,]*(len(b)-len(a)), b + [0,]*(len(a)-len(b))))

# вывод результата
print(list(c))
```

Результат:

> [2, 4, 6, 4]

#### Вариант 3:

В Python 3.8 появился "морж" - оператор :=
Если важно не повторить функционал:

```
# заполнение переменных
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3]

# обработка
c = map(sum, zip(a + [0, ] * (x := len(b) - len(a)), b + [0, ] * -x))

# вывод результата
print(list(c))

Результат:
> [2, 4, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Вариант забавный, но 1) он меняет исходные списки, 2) повторяет функционал `itertools.zip_longest`

Comment: Так то пусть будет, разные ответы это хорошо )

Comment: согласен, не без недостатков, но как вариант для "по быстрому"

Comment: добавил варианты без изменения исходных списков и вариант для Python 3.8 без повтора функционала

Answer (score 3):

Если вы еще не "прошли 'from' 'import'", то наиболее простой вариант выглядит вот так:

```
с=list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b))
```

или так:

```
c1 = [x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)] + (a if len(a) >= len(b) else b)[min(len(a), len(b)):]
```

При необходимости обернуть это в вызов функции, надеюсь, сможете сделать самостоятельно: на вход a и b, указанные выражения - в качестве параметра в return.

Comment: Спасибо тебе за ответ)
мне нужно просто без комприхенш`на 
может просто через def и внутри def через for
буду рад если поможете  = )

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас списка ВСЕГДА точно будут одной длины, то можно воспользоваться генератор списков и zip:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

c = [x+y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
print(c) #[5, 7, 9]
```

Но если вы НЕ уверены, что длина списков будет одинаковой хоть раз, то здесь нужно воспользоваться крутой библиотекой itertools:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 10]

c = [x+y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0) #fillvalue нужен, если ваши списки разных рамеров и там где не достаёт элементов, добьёт нулями.
print(c) #[5, 7, 9, 10]
```

---

Ответ на комментарий:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def add_list(a, b):
   c = [x+y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]
   return c

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 10]

summ_list = add_list(a, b)
print(summ_list)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
а еще есть варианты  с помощью def 
я просто прохожу курсы

Написать функцию add_list(numbers1, numbers2) которой передаются два списка.
 
Функция должна вернуть новый список каждый элемент которого - сумма соответствующих элементов из оригинальых списков. Если один из списков длинее другого, просто скопировать элемент.
 
Примеры:
 
numbers([1,2,3], [3,4,5]) -> [4,6,8]
numbers([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]) -> [5,7,9,7]

Comment: Добавил в ответ, то что вы просили, удачного освоения Python и если вам мой ответ помог, пометьте его как верный

Comment: я просто еще не прошел 'from' 'import' и comprehension 
я есть простой вариант там через for 
=))))

Comment: можете сделать просто import и использовать как itertools.zip_longest

Answer (score 1):

без 'from' 'import' и comprehension

```
def sum_lists(lst_1, lst_2):
    result = []

    if len(lst_1) != len(lst_2):  # если списки разного размера
        if len(lst_1) > len(lst_2):
            diff = len(lst_1) - len(lst_2)
            for i, v in enumerate(lst_1):
                if i >= len(lst_1) - diff:
                    result.append(v)
                else:
                    result.append(v + lst_2[i])
        else:
            diff = len(lst_2) - len(lst_1)
            for i, v in enumerate(lst_2):
                if i >= len(lst_2) - diff:
                    result.append(v)
                else:
                    result.append(v + lst_1[i])
    else:  # если списки одинаковы по размеру
        for i, v in enumerate(lst_1):
            result.append(v + lst_2[i])

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Так работает даже с многомерными масивами, главное чтобы размерности совпадали:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([3,4 ,5 ,9])
B=np.array([1 ,5, 7 ,9])

print( A+B )
#[ 4  9 12 18]
```